# Django ModelForm input constraint

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

i have models containing several datefield fields, and i want to make the user be able to enter values through ModelForm but i want to make a restriction that the entered date values must be greater than the previous datefield and lesser than the next datefield.

Comment: You can override the `clean` function for that. But if this should always the case, it is better to override the `clean` function on the *model*, not in the form.

Comment: thanks for answering, can you please code a Model example in case i make on the Model?

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add extra validation by overriding the `clean` function of the form, like:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    date1 = forms.DateField()
    date2 = forms.DateField()
    date3 = forms.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        date1 = cleaned_data.get('date1')
        date2 = cleaned_data.get('date2')
        date3 = cleaned_data.get('date3')
        if not (date1 <= date2 <= date3):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Date fields should be ordered')
        return cleaned_data
```

If this constraint however hold on the model, it is more elegant to override the `clean` function of the model:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Foo(models.Model):
    date1 = models.DateField()
    date2 = models.DateField()
    date3 = models.DateField()

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.date1 <= self.date2 <= self.date3):
            raise ValidationError('Date fields should be ordered')
        return cleaned_data
```

Note that model cleaning is *not* done when saving a model, but a `ModelForm` will call the `clean` function on the model. So it is still possible to create `Foo` objects where the constraint does not hold. But if you would for example construct multiple `FooForm`s, these will all automatically enforce this.

Comment: Worked fine, my gratitude. @Willem